# $(\frac{3}{2})^h = log_{3/2} h = \log_{2} h / \log_{2} 3/2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$(\frac{3}{2})^h$, then take the log of it:  $\log_{3/2} h = \log_{2} h / \log_{2} 3/2$

could someone explain steps please.

I thought $(3/2)^h$ would be $h\log (3/2)$

nor do I get how they got to this $\log_{3/2} h = \log_{2} h / \log_{2} 3/2$

Which property are they optimizing?

Comment: For me also, the first line doesn't seem to make sense. Also, what is $n$? Where does this come from?

Comment: n should be h - whoops

Comment: Thanks for the feedback & update of the question text. You should also update the title, including removing the first "=" as that is not true. In addition, please let us know where the first line comes from. Thanks.

Comment: This question makes no sense. What exactly are you asking? What is the context?

Comment: How does $\log_{3/2} h = \log_{2} h / \log_{2} 3/2$. What properties are used?

Comment: Taking the log of something gives you .... something else.  You can't say, $M $.  Take the log of it.  That's $\log M $.  You can't then say $M=\log M $, because... they are different things.

Comment: " nor do I get how they got to this" how *who* got to this?  Whose doing all this stuff? Whoever it is, don't pay attention to it because it's utter crap.  It'd be too hard to explain what is wrong with it so it's easier just to say it has so much wrong it has nothing worthwhile for us to waste our time with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take the (natural) log of $\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^h$, then it is indeed $h\log\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)$.

It appears that whatever source you got this from attempted to take the log base $\frac{3}{2}$ of $\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^h$. But this would be $\log_{3/2}\left(\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^h\right)=h\log_{3/2}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)=h$, not $\log_{3/2}(h)$.

One rule of logarithms is that $\log_a(b) = \frac{\log_c(b)}{\log_c(a)}$ (this is the change of base formula). Applying this with $a=\frac{3}{2}$, $b=h$, and $c=2$, we do indeed have $\log_{3/2}(h) = \log_2(h)/\log_2(3/2)$.

In conclusion,

- $\log\left(\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^h\right)\neq \log_{3/2}(h)$ (in any base)
- $\log_{3/2}(h) = \log_2(h)/\log_2(3/2)$ by the change of base formula.

Comment: As such, it seems the $\log_{3/2}{\left(h\right)} = \log_{2}{\left(h\right)} / \log_{2}{\left(3/2\right)}$ equation is true for any positive $h$. Thus, it doesn't really have anything directly to do with the original value of $\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^h$.

Comment: That is correct, the value of $h$ is irrelevant (well, it has to be positive to take the log of it, but that's it).